# PDF Reporting using Selenium Web Driver with C#, Nunit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, nunit-3.0

I have been using Extent report but that only generate report in HTML But I Want something similar that can generate with PDF

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a work around for it. So what I have done is Added A css file with some adjustments in to the html and was able to covert to PDF and print with attached screenshots.